# Java - Cannot refer to a non-final variable

Tags: java

New to android.
What should I edit to get rid of a strange "cannot refer to a non-final variable button inside an inner class defined in a different method?

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle SavedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(SavedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        //Listeneři
        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                button1.setText("ok");
```

Comment: Declare button1 as `final`.

Comment: Did you try googling what the error means? Its not an android specific problem, its a Java related problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to this..

```
 final Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    //Listeneři
    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            button1.setText("ok");
```

or

you can declare the button variable reference as global..

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is not possible.

[JLS # chapter 8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3)

> Any local variable, formal parameter, or exception parameter used but not declared in an inner class must be declared final.
>
> Any local variable used but not declared in an inner class must be definitely assigned (§16) before the body of the inner class.

Make that variable as `final`  before using it in `innerclass`,So that you can get permission to use it.

```
final Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
```

Like wise, make remaining also `final`, If you are using them inside listener..

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the button variables as 'final' as below

```
final Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
final Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
```

so,that button1 and button2 cannot be re-initialized.

Comment: Why `button2` should be final ?

Comment: we need to make any references as final before we attach listeners to them. so, that it will ensure that there is no change after listeners are set

Comment: Assuming button2 is also gonna be attached to listener.

Comment: Awesome. I got another error, tho:
onclicklistener cannot be resolved to a type?

Comment: @user2890391 You just `import` that.

Comment: that's it :) it will do

Comment: onClickListener is already imported. I also have a problem: onclicklistener is not applicable for teh argumentz: new onClickListener

Comment: @user2890391 Post complete code, You may have some syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle SavedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(SavedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    //Listeneři
    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Button button = (Button)v;
            button.setText("ok");
        }
    }
```

no need make the variable as final also...

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Eclipse? If so, using the quick fix menu will help you solve issues such as non-final variables, and missing import statements.

http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fconcept-quickfix-assist.htm

On Windows, place the cursor on the error and press Ctrl+1 to open the quick fix menu. Pressing enter will (usually) solve the error satisfactorily.

Answer (score 0):

U have two ways to slove the problem,
1. change
              `Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);`

to         `final Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);`

2.define the button1 out of the function.like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle SavedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(SavedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Listeneři
    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            button1.setText("ok");
```

Comment: Surely that will try to find the buttons when the activity is created (ie before onCreate is called), but the buttons don't exist until setContentView is called...?